# How to export canvas image using jsPDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, jspdf

I am developing an application that generates some graphics using `canvas`. Now I need to export these graphics to PDF. What's wrong with my code?

I think the problem is the `src` using `dataURI`:

```
function uri(obj) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById(obj);
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg,1.0");
  var img = document.getElementById('minha_imagem');
  img.src = dataURL;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/suheidorn/pen/zGMdrq)

Comment: you need to use `addImage()` method, which takes a dataURL as first argument

Answer (score 3):

This was my question too.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById(canvas_obj);
doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'JPEG', 0, 0, 100, 100);
```

**Its resulting a pdf with black image.**

http://codepen.io/doriclaudino/pen/KprqzR

I think you need use a last version of JSPDF with anothers includes.

Comment: Thanks kaiido, it work perfectly.
Do you have any idea to fromHTML method export the canvas or image with src base64? (maybe putting a background image).

Comment: Well I never gone into jspdf code but it seems `addImage` is the only method working rn. Spoke too fast : https://twitter.com/mrrio/status/429276804143017984?lang=en

Answer (score 1):

I know is too late but I need to do the  same and solved it with jsPDF and html2canvas

```
const canvasElement = await html2canvas(
      document.querySelector('#wave-spectrogram')
    );
```

You have yout canvasElement, just pass it to jsPDF

```
pdf.addImage(canvasElement, 'PNG', x, y, width, height)
pdf.save()
```

That's all

Comment: What version of jsPDF?

Answer (score 0):

a bit late maybe,

I just had the same issue a month ago, I resolved it like this

```
function getPDFFileButton () {
            return html2canvas($("#toSaveAsPDF"), {
                background: "#ffffff",
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    var imgWidth = (canvas.width * 25.4) / 240;
                    var imgHeight = (canvas.height * 25.4) / 240; 
                    var table = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                    table.addImage(myImage, 'JPEG', 15, 2, imgWidth, imgHeight); // 2: 19
                    table.save('Statistiques.pdf');
                }
            });
        }
```

you can set the background of your generated PDF with this line `background: "#ffffff",`

Hope this can be helpful,

Answer (score 0):

To avoid a black background of your image when exporting from canvas, choose png compression instead. That works fine !